# When connect to the database I get an error `driver not loaded`

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, database-connection, qt5

**First:** I am using `Qt v5.3.1` with `MinGW 4.8.2`, and `Window 7 32bit` platform.

When run my application in `windows 7`, I found it is working fine in connect to database only if Qt environment is installed, also when move the same application to another platform like `windows xp` by `Virtual PC`, unfortunately I found the connection to database fail too, and an error message appears `driver not loaded`, but the application works fine but without connection to database.

**My attempts:**

- I have used `QSqlDatabase::drivers()` to check if `sqlite` supported
  in the system, and the result was, `sqlite` database
  supported with many other types.
- I have used `isValid()` to check if there is a valid driver, but the
  function return `false`, and this indicates that the database type is
  not available or could not be loaded.

[image]

[image]

The following is the code that I use:

**database.h**

```
class database
{
public:
    static QSqlDatabase db;
    static QString dbPath;
    database();

    static void connect();
    static bool openConnection();
    static void CloseConnection();
    static void removeDB();
};
```

**database.cpp**

```
QSqlDatabase database::db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
QString database::dbPath = "";

database::database(){
}

void database::connect(){
    database::dbPath = "database.db";
    database::db.setDatabaseName(database::dbPath);
}

void database::CloseConnection(){
    database::db.close();
}

void database::removeDB(){
    database::db.removeDatabase(database::db.defaultConnection);
}
```

Also I have checked if the database file exists or not, and also I have opened the connection to database.

```
database::connect();
  if(QFile::exists(database::dbPath)){
      if(database::db.open()){
          ui->label->setText(ui->label->text() + "Connected.");
          QSqlQuery qry;
          qry.prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
          qry.exec();
          while(qry.next()){
              ui->listWidget->addItem(qry.value("username").toString());
              ui->listWidget->item(ui->listWidget->count()-1)->setData(Qt::UserRole, qry.value("id").toString());
            }
          database::CloseConnection();
        }else{
          ui->label->setText(ui->label->text() + "Failed to connect to database");
        }
    }else{
      ui->label->setText(ui->label->text() + "Database file does not found");
    }
```

I don't know what's the problem in the connection with database, everything is alright, and there is no missing files in my application, and the database file beside the executable file.

**How to solve this problem ?**

Comment: You posted absolutely no code that checks for errors or return codes.  Aren't you supposed to do that first?  As a matter of fact, all of your functions return `void`, so I don't see how you check for error conditions.

Comment: What should the path of the database file be? (`dbPath` does not contain a path.)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Thanks, I have been updated my question, to clarify this point.

Comment: @CL.: Thanks, I have been specified the path of database file here `database::dbPath = "database.db";` which means the database file beside the executable file or in the main directory of application. and this works fine on `windows 7`. but the problem on `windows xp`.

Comment: That is a file name without a path. The database file will be put into the current directory, which is not always the executable's directory. How do you ensure that you have write access to the directory?

Comment: @CL. : Ok, what is the correct path, which will work fine on all platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
QSqlDatabase database::db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
```

This line is the problem. This is global code (code that gets run before `main`), which in turn attempts to load a Qt Plugin before a `QCoreApplication` instance has been created. This call will therefore fail.

**Solution**: leave it default-initialized and call `addDatabase` *after* creating a `QCoreApplication`.

**Better solution**: *stop using global variables*; you can open your DB connection in `main` and pass the connection handle to the classes which need it (also note that `QtSql` classes natively support the concept of a "connection name", so you can access that connection from everywhere, given the right name of the conection).

Answer (score 0):

In Windows XP, `\Program Files` is not writable by normal users.
(Neither is it in Windows 7, but depending on the configuration, some paths might be redirected.)

Use [QDesktopServices::DataLocation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdesktopservices.html#StandardLocation-enum) (Qt 4) or [QStandardPaths::DataLocation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html#StandardLocation-enum) (Qt 5).

Comment: Thank you, but can you give me an example to change the current path `database::dbPath = "database.db";` to the correct path by using `QStandardPaths::DataLocation`.

Comment: `QDir::cleanPath(QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DataLocation) + "/database.db")`

Comment: Unfortunately, error message: `Database file does not found`. now does not want to connect to database on `windows 7` or `windows xp`, because the wrong path of database file `C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/QtApplication/database.db`, but the correct path is `C:\QtApp`.

Answer (score 0):

> `database::dbPath = "database.db"` means the database file beside the executable file or in the main directory of application"

This statement is false. The path you gave is relative to the current working directory, **not** to the location of the executable file. If the working directory and the executable's path happen to be the same, you merely ran into a coincidence that can't be depended on. Never mind that the executable's location is not writable, so there's no point in storing any variable data there!

You need to store that database somewhere else, and you must be explicit about where it's stored.

Comment: Thank you, but I need an example to clarify the idea.

Comment: The problem now it is don't want to open the database. `if(database::db.open()){}else{ui->label->setText(ui->label->text() + "Failed to connect to database");}` this message is always appears `Failed to connect to database`. and I have been changed the path to `c:/database.db`.

Comment: @LionKing Well, is there a database there?

Comment: Yes, the database file is in that path. Also I have used `QSqlDatabase::lastError()`, and the result is displays an error: `driver not loaded`. Note that there is a folder in the main application folder named `sqldrivers` and the contents of this folder is  collection of files as the following: `qsqlite.dll`, `qsqlmysql.dll`, `qsqlodbc.dll`, `qsqlpsql.dll`.